# WebSocket connection to 'wss://ip:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, websocket, streaming

```
var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
    {
        var callbacks = {};
        var ws_url = url;
        var conn;

        this.bind = function(event_name, callback){
            callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
            callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
            return this;// chainable
        };

        this.send = function(event_name, event_data){
            //this.conn.send(event_data);
            this.conn.onopen = () => this.conn.send(event_data);
            return this;
        };

        this.connect = function() {
            if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
                this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
            else
                this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

            // dispatch to the right handlers
            this.conn.onmessage = function(evt){
                dispatch('message', evt.data);
            };

            this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
            this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
        };

        this.disconnect = function() {
            this.conn.close();
        };

        var dispatch = function(event_name, message){
            if(message == null || message == "")
            {
            } 
            else
            {
                video(message);
            }
        }
    };

    var Server;
    function send( text )
    {
        Server.send( 'message', text );
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Server = new FancyWebSocket('wss://103.211.219.27:8080');
        Server.bind('open', function()
        {
        });
        Server.bind('close', function(data)
        {
        });
        Server.bind('message', function(payload)
        {
        });
        Server.connect();
    });
```

This is my previous question as I was asked but not getting any answer. In this code I am building video live streaming through IP and Port but I am getting error i.e

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://ip:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I don't know why this is occurring. I have already have SSL of my domain that's why I am using `wss` but still I have same problem. I always got this error in my console on line `this.conn = new WebSocket(url);`. So, How can I establish successful connection through websocket? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: are you on localhost ?

Comment: No I am on live server @BilalSiddiqui

Comment: Is port 8080 open for TCP IN/OUT ?

Comment: Actually, I don't have any idea about TCP IN/OUT. How can I check ?@BilalSiddiqui

Comment: What is your server? and where it is deployed ? eg. amazon/apache ....

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui it is on bigrock

Comment: As much I know, godaddy doesn't opens a custom port for shared hosting. You must raise a concern to godday support. They will help you for sure.

Comment: sorry @BilalSiddiqui my server is on bigrock

Comment: I am not aware of bigrock, but still you need to reach support to open a port for you (for websocket handshake).